# how affiche color in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have used a Autocompletetextview in my application And it works well, but I want one more thing, that the letters entered by user in my autocompletetextview should appears in color.please, what should I add in code so that it will show me as I want......Here is my code

```js
class afficheclient extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = null;
        String line = null;

        /**
         * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread. The
         * specified parameters are the parameters passed to {@link #execute}
         * by the caller of this task.
         * <p/>
         * This method can call {@link #publishProgress} to publish updates
         * on the UI thread.
         *
         * @param params The parameters of the task.
         * @return A result, defined by the subclass of this task.
         * @see #onPreExecute()       * @see #onPostExecute
         * @see #publishProgress
         */

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.16/toutclient.php");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("Pass 2", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }

            try {
                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json = null;
                final String[] str1 = new String[JA.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
                    json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    str1[i] = json.getString("D_CLIENT");
                }

                final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                        findViewById(R.id.autoComplete1);
                final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
                    list.add(str1[i]);
                }

                Collections.sort(list);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                text.setThreshold(1);
                text.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                text.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   //     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.get(arg2).toString(),
                               // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please specify what you want actually and try to rephrase your question

Comment: I want when I have the list of data that contains the letter that I seek displays all the normal sentence except the letter entered in color , I hope that I am clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you want to show color in auto suggestions? In Asynctask you should first execute OnPreExecute method.After that all the back work of url should inside doinbackground method.